# When proving the Hypothetical Syllogism inference rule, why must you assume that p is true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I recently started learning Discrete Maths and currently studying rules of inference. I was looking at a proof of Hypothetical Syllogism, aka:

> *P*→*Q*
> *Q*→*R*
> ∴ *P*→*R*

and I came across this proof of the above rule:

> (1) *P→Q*   (Hypothesis)
>   (2) *Q→R*   (Hypothesis)
>   (3) *P* (Assumption)
>   (4) *Q* (1 and 3: Modus Ponens)
>   (5) *R* (2 and 4: Modus Ponens)
>   (6) *P→R* (3 - 5: if P, then R)
>   ∴ *((P→Q) ∧ (Q→R)) → (P→R)*

I understand all the steps, except for step (3). Why do we need to assume that *P* is true? In that case, isn't it just a conditional proof and no longer a tautology? If *P* is false, would't the proof no longer hold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$(3), (4), (5)$ can be seen as a subproof, within the larger proof.

We assume $P$, in order to see what follows from $P$.

In this case, after two applications of modus ponens, we see that $R$ follows from that assumption, together with the hypotheses.

So we have proven **if** P, then R. (Which we state in line $(6)$. In symbols, we have proven $P \rightarrow R$. We haven't *proven* P. But we have proven P implies R. If P is false, the implication is true (any implication with a false antecedent is true). However, we know that **if** P is true, then so must be R.

Answer (score 1):

The rule says (something like) "to conclude $P\rightarrow R$, it suffices to conclude $R$ having assumed $P$". The point is that if $P$ happens to be true then $R$ must be true as well. If $P$ is false, it doesn't matter because $P\rightarrow R$ is automatically true in that case.

Answer (score 0):

In any axiomatic system where this rule is valid you do *not* have to assume "p" in order to prove this rule, since in any axiomatic system where you can use conditional introduction a rule of inference, CpCqp and CCpCqrCCpqCpr are either axioms or theorems.  Suppose the axioms are the following, in Polish/Lukasiewicz notation:

1. CpCqp.
2. CCpCqrCCpqCpr.

Then we can prove the rule as follows:

```
hypothesis  1 Cpq
hypothesis  2 Cqr
axiom 1     3 CCqrCpCqr
3, 2        4 CpCqr
axiom 2     5 CCpCqrCCpqCpr
detach 5, 4 6 CCpqCpr
detach 6, 1 7 Cpr
```